# Setting up a system for future module-level updates

Tags: c#, parse-platform, architecture, module, updates

I m currently working on a mobile app (mostly using .NET c# for the logic, parse.com for cloud databases, and unity3D for the interface) and I plan to make it evolve over a certain time period.

I would like my architecture to allow me to smoothly update the app, module-by-module, as it s frequently seen on various systems, i.e. when a new module becomes available on a server, the app is informed, the new module version is downloaded, and replaces the older version of the same module.

I have some ideas on how to do that, but I feel this challenge must have been theorized and discussed here and there. Good practices may exist, and typical issues may also be known. 
Any suggestions (and refs) on how to properly design such an "update-by-module" sub-system?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: you might want to read about https://osgi.codeplex.com/ and http://mef.codeplex.com/. i can not give much help, as i only know OSGi for Java, which definitely allows you to do what you want.

Comment: thanks a lot, will have a look. I m not looking for a language-specific solution. If i grab the philosophy of your example in order to get some inspiration, that will already be very nice :)

Comment: :-) ... i though you might want to use a standard, instead of reinventing one yourself. again, i can not speak for C#, but in the java world, many millions of man-hours have gone into this standard and software dealing with it already, so it is generally most sane to use it, instead of using it as an inspiration only. either way.. good luck!

Comment: yep, I would ideally use it as is (I posted my comment before actually realizing mef was implemented in c# - thought it was java). I still have to figure out if I can have it working in my project. As I mentioned, I m connecting my work with Unity3d, which requires me to uses an older .Net implementation (3.5 currently if I m right) so there may be compatibility issues. In which case i would probably still use it as an inspiration, which is definitely suboptimal and more time consuming, but still better than having no clue ;-). Thanks again.